# How to define request.getContextPath() as baseUrl in RequireJS config?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, requirejs

Newbie question: I just started RequireJS today and I'm trying to set the request.getContextPath() as my baseUrl in my config file.

I am using JSP. On each JSP page I import scripts.jsp in the head:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<%String context = request.getContextPath();%> // i.e. /www.myUrl.com/myContextPath

<c:set var="context" value="<%=context %>"/>

<script data-main="${context}/js/config" src="${context}/js/require.js"></script>
<script>
require(['config'], function(){
    // all dependencies have loaded
})
```

Inside config.js I have this:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'libs',
paths:{
    jquery:'jquery-2.2.4/jquery-2.2.4.min',
    bootstrap:'bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min',
    dataTables: 'datatables.min'
    }
});
```

The problem is that it tries to load the libraries and doesn't have my context path so it'll attempt something like this:

www.myUrl.com/NOTmyContextPath/libs/jqueryLib

I need to get ${context} in the baseUrl. What is the best way to get that value in there?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

UPDATE: This appears to be a Spring mapping issue and I'm now lost because I'm a front-end developer. The server error I receive is the following:

WARN : 2017-03-17 16:08:04:636       org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound No mapping found for HTTP     request with URI [/myContextPath/app/dir/js/myFolder/libs/jquery-2.2.4/jquery-2.2.4.min] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myContextPath'

I don't think I need to add a new servlet mapping in web.xml and I'd rather not use window.location or something along those lines to get the application context. What's the best way to rectify this?

Comment: you should use <mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location="/app/"  cache-period="120202"/> in servlet.xml and set other static files using "app" mapping where you put static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer using JS on another Stack overflow post:

```
function getContextPath() {
   return window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));
}

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: getContextPath() + '/js/ops/libs',
    paths:{
        jquery:'jQuery-2.2.4/jquery-2.2.4.min',
        bootstrap:'Bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min',
        dataTables: 'datatables.min',
    }
});
```